# Using jQuery to Focus a Field on Hover after a Delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to cause a field to be focused when hovered, but only after a 3 second delay. Clearly I'm doing it wrong:

```js
var timer;

function focusTimer() {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('#input').focus(),
        3000;
    })
}

$('#input').hover(function () {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  
    focusTimer();
});
```

```css
#input:focus {
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

You're placing the 3000 inside the function. move it to outside

```
timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('#input').focus(),
        3000;
       ^^^^^^^
    })
```

Should be

```
timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('#input').focus();
    },3000);
```

Snippet

```js
var timer;

function focusTimer() {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('#input').focus();
        
    },3000)
}

$('#input').hover(function () {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  
    focusTimer();
});
```

```css
#input:focus {
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input">
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **transition-delay**:

```
#input {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 5s;
  transition:width 5s;
  transition-delay:5s;
  width:100px;
}

#input:focus {
  width:200px;
}
```

To hover over the input:

```
#input:hover {
 width:200px;
}
```

Comment: me too. +1 for thinking out side of the box.

Comment: Disregard, got it to work. However, this isn't quite what I want. The JS method above focuses the input after hovering for a period of time. This requires the input be clicked.

Comment: For this to work when hovering, use: hover, instead of: focus. input:hover.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var timer;

function focusTimer() {
    timer = setTimeout(function () { //change your setTimeout like this
        $('#input').focus();
       
    },3000);

 
}

$('#input').hover(function () {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  
    focusTimer();
});
```

```css
#input:focus {
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input">
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#i").hover(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#i").focus();
  }, 1000);
})
```

```css
#i {
  width:300px;
  transition:width 1s;

#i:focus {
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="i">
```

Comment: I like the brevity of the function here.